# Can't boot into Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7 (grouper)

Tags: boot, system-installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have been trying to install Ubuntu touch on Nexus 7 (grouper, WiFi) for a couple days now, and no luck. I am using manual install method ([from this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)) because other automatic tools don't work. Also using [Ubuntu touch daily pre-installed images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/).

I tried using Ubuntu recovery provided with other images, but received error and `audodeploy.zip` would not install after pushing it to `/sdcard/autodeploy.zip`

```
E: Can't open /cache /recovery/ubuntu_command
Can't find autodeploy.zip
```

I have also tried using CWM recovery, but no luck there either. Device just get's stuck on Google boot logo.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
It looks like `/sdcard` is actually a link to `/data/media/` which seems to get erased every boot.

Comment: What 'automatic' tools did you try, and how did these fail? *The daily builds have generally worked (to install), but continue to exhibit issues (which vary) on **Nexus 4**, **Nexus 7**, and **Nexus 10** - as changes break (or improve) existing features.*

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same issue and the warning messages scared me, but I just waited a bit longer and it eventually continues on its own.  I had to wait almost 10 minutes for that first screen to pass the:

```
E: Can't open /cache /recovery/ubuntu_command
Can't find autodeploy.zip
```

message.  Maybe give it some more time.